# At the end of the random song, restart with another one

Tags: javascript, html

I created a script that plays a random song, but, when the song ends, obviously it stops.
I really don't know how to play an another random sound at the end of the song.

```
function getRandomSounds() {
        var sounds = new Array();
        sounds[0]="ms1/7_58_LEFT.mp3";
        sounds[1]="ms1/6_15.mp3";
        sounds[2]="ms1/7_58_RIGHT.mp3";
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length);
        document.getElementById("myaudio").src=sounds[randomNum];
        
         }
        getRandomSounds();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event

Answer (score 1):

There are perhaps easier ways to achieve this, but building on top of the snippet you already have, I would:

```js
function getRandomSounds() {
  var sounds = new Array();
  sounds[0] = "ms1/7_58_LEFT.mp3";
  sounds[1] = "ms1/6_15.mp3";
  sounds[2] = "ms1/7_58_RIGHT.mp3";
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
  document.getElementById("myaudio").src = sounds[randomNum];

}

getRandomSounds();

document.getElementById("myaudio").addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
  getRandomSounds();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Web API instead of set the reference value!

Use Element.setAttribute(), it will search the DOM tree.

If the property already exists, then the browser will change the DOM tree node property!

I try both methods to change the DOM tree node property, you can check for my example on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/rusaqosoji/edit?html,js,console,output), open the dev tool (F12), as you can see the property by using setAttribute method is change the src successfully.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

console.log(foo.src)
foo.src = "ms1/7_58_LEFT.mp3"
console.log(foo.src)
      
foo.setAttribute('src', '"ms1/7_58_LEFT.mp3');
```

Here is the MDN Document, hope that helps you :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute